# Hive Query Giving Different Results Than SQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have two tables, called 'game' and 'team', in a MySQL database.  They are of the following form:

```
game:
+-----+------+
| gid | temp |
+-----+------+
|   1 | 79   |
|   2 | 78   |
|   3 | 109  |
|   4 | 77   |
|   5 | 90   |
|   6 | 89   |
|   7 | 65   |
|   8 | 71   |
|   9 | 89   |
|  10 | 80   |
+-----+------+

team:
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
| gid | tname | ry  | py  |
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
|   1 | SF    |  92 | 247 |
|   1 | ATL   |  95 | 264 |
|   2 | JAC   | 119 | 279 |
|   2 | CLE   |  96 | 153 |
|   3 | PHI   | 306 | 119 |
|   3 | DAL   |  67 | 100 |
|   4 | NYJ   | 118 | 261 |
|   4 | GB    |  62 | 149 |
|   5 | IND   | 119 | 267 |
|   5 | KC    |  74 | 206 |
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
```

There are more columns, but these are the relevant ones.  I have exported these to Hive (which I am running in pseudodistributed mode) using Sqoop, and I'm trying to run a simple query; however, I get vastly different results than if I ran the same query in MySQL.

For instance, in Hive if I run the query (to get average yards per game in sub-freezing temperatures)

```
SELECT tname, AVG(ry+py) as ypg FROM team INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT gid FROM game WHERE temp<=32) AS cold
    ON team.gid=cold.gid GROUP BY tname;
```

I get

```
OK
ARI 263.0
ATL 271.5
BAL 309.77777777777777
BUF 304.5
CAR 278.6666666666667
CHI 292.6333333333333
CIN 309.77272727272725
CLE 290.6666666666667
DAL 255.85714285714286
DEN 366.5
DET 327.44444444444446
GB  373.75471698113205
HOU 391.75
IND 303.9
JAC 302.0
KC  346.4782608695652
MIA 325.1666666666667
MIN 325.6666666666667
NE  358.5
NO  369.3333333333333
NYG 347.57142857142856
NYJ 310.27777777777777
OAK 326.7
PHI 344.3
PIT 359.969696969697
SD  337.14285714285717
SEA 289.45454545454544
SF  340.14285714285717
STL 452.0
TB  348.3333333333333
TEN 305.3076923076923
WAS 290.3333333333333
Time taken: 30.172 seconds, Fetched: 32 row(s)
```

whereas, running the identical query in MySQL gives

```
+-------+----------+
| tname | ypg      |
+-------+----------+
| ARI   | 339.7283 |
| ATL   | 347.1628 |
| BAL   | 304.5625 |
| BUF   | 305.1250 |
| CAR   | 333.7179 |
| CHI   | 313.3462 |
| CIN   | 316.9167 |
| CLE   | 301.1579 |
| DAL   | 356.4805 |
| DEN   | 357.8298 |
| DET   | 366.3509 |
| GB    | 372.9351 |
| HOU   | 334.9915 |
| IND   | 362.3732 |
| JAC   | 325.9444 |
| KC    | 339.1622 |
| MIA   | 318.6667 |
| MIN   | 341.0000 |
| NE    | 368.5614 |
| NO    | 408.4219 |
| NYG   | 370.2500 |
| NYJ   | 314.8788 |
| OAK   | 327.7143 |
| PHI   | 354.2619 |
| PIT   | 359.4565 |
| SD    | 352.2105 |
| SEA   | 349.8444 |
| SF    | 320.9744 |
| STL   | 348.1736 |
| TB    | 309.9310 |
| TEN   | 314.4222 |
| WAS   | 362.3548 |
+-------+----------+
32 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why are these different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Hive query returns the correct result.  This was because there were a number of missing temperatures in the 'game' table, which MySQL was treating as 0s (hence including in the calculation of yards per game in sub-freezing temperatures).